# Is it possible to access other class method without passing method parameter

Tags: java, selenium, oop, cucumber

I have scenario where i want to access another class method which is returning something.

The method in another class is expecting parameter

Example:

```
public class Class1()
{
    public Response postResponse(String getURL,DataTable dataTable)
    {
        /*..
        my post request code here
        ..*/
        return postData;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Class2()
{
    public void readPostResponse()
    {
        /*..
         here i want to access Class1.postResponse method and I don't want to pass the 
         parameter.. 
        ..*/
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: then pass two null's, but keep in mind that may cause NullPointerExceptions

Comment: I will try this as I just want ready something which 'postResponse' returning. I am working on automation, if i pass null values then will it affect test parallel execution ?

Comment: passing null might crash the code. Just( assume there'll be impact

Comment: thanks for the information is there any other ways or documents that can help me to resolve this scenario

Comment: Just FYI. i can make `postResponse` static but that again leads to some other problems in parallel execution

Comment: well, you could look at the code itself.

Comment: Yeah i got null pointer exception when i use null.

Comment: so, passing the parameters isn't optional. either you pass valid parameters, or simply don't call the method

Comment: What is the point of calling method expecting parameters without parameters? What do you expect to get? Method logic implies there are some parameters in place, hence logic without parameters is undefined.

Comment: @AlexeyR. In my case i am writing cucumber steps to perform `REST` post request, i am using Cucumber DataTable and passing it as a parameter for my post request and then post request returning response. This response i want to read from other class step definitions.

Comment: @Stultuske passing NO parameters is not the same as passing NULL parameters. Passing `null` is passing a reference that points to null area of memory (address zero - which is blocked by the OS). Passing no parameters to a method when the method requires parameters will result in a compiling error. Therefore, it is impossible to do.

Comment: @hfontanez I'm well aware of the difference between null and an instance. When it comes to parameters, the null can be seen as a placeholder, a default value, yes. But it's not an actual value/instance. So: when passing a value is optional, you can ignore it and pass null. Then the method will use some default value instead. But if that's not the case, you have to pass an actual value, and that seems to be the case here.

Comment: @Stultuske But that's not really what the OP asked. Null or not null, you are still passing parameters. The OP stated (perhaps incorrectly) that he or she wishes to pass no parameters.

Comment: @hfontanez which may just have been a badly worded way to say "I don't know what values to pass", or "I don't want to pass specific values for each scenario". Without further  explanation from the OP, that's pretty hard to know.

Comment: It has been about 5 days since you posted this question. Two answers have been posted and you haven't provide any feedback on any of them. While there is nothing against this, it is somewhat impolite in my  opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices:

- pass parameters. This is preferred way. Because parameters of method contains some info that can be used in method
- mock or stub your parameters if it is possible. It looks like you are using Selenium, but Selenium starts a real browser
- pass null parameters.It is not really preferred way because your method can work incorrectly without necessary data

Comment: DEFINITELY the case in the first bullet. You can still do the the second, but I can't think of a case where this is significantly different than the first case. The third bullet (IMO) is a huge code smell and should be avoided at all cost; especially considering that you have the choice outlined in bullet comment #1.

Answer (score 1):

I started to write this before @StepUp posted his answer. I am going to cover the way I think it should be done based on what I understood by "I don't want to pass the parameter"

It sounds you want to create a default case. This example is arbitrary since your code is not really specific. In general terms, when talking about functions, a default case for a function is a method with the same name, with no parameter list. For example,

```
public class Class1 
{
    /**
     * Default case
     */
    public Response postResponse() 
    {
        // Some code here
    }

    /**
     * Specific case (the ellipsis means some parameter list) 
     */
    public Response postResponse(...)
    {
        // Some code here
    }
}
```

In your case, you may want to create a default step definition that you can invoke independently in a specific scenario, or you may want to call it from the same scenario with or without parameters specified in your data table. You can still take the same approach. I want to mention that having a default case, doesn't mean that you absolutely need to pass null parameters. 99% of the time, this is a bad idea. All you need to do is to pass some default values.

```
public class Class1 
{
    /**
     * Default case
     */
    public Response postResponse() 
    {
        String url = "..."; // maybe a base URL here?
        Object col1 = ...;
        Object col2 = ...;
        handlePostResponse(url, col1, col2);
        // Do other stuff?
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * Specific case 
     */
    public Response postResponse(String url, DataTable dataTable)
    {
        // Iterate through data table and call handlePostResponse for each row
        return response;
    }


    // This method wraps how to handle post response. The ellipsis might be the elements of the data table
    private void handlePostResponse(String url, Object col1, Object col2) 
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Now that you have this, you can call your method in Class 2 that needs to invoke the default case in Class 1.

```
public class Class2 
{
    public void readPostResponse()
    {
        Class1 clazz1 = new Class1();
        Response resp = clazz1.postResponse(); // calling no parameters (default) case (you may not need to get the response object (ignore it altogether)
        // Do more stuff?
    }
}
```

Remember that every time you pass `null` to a function or return `null` from a function, you may have to do some sort of input or output validation to ensure the object about to be used to invoke other methods is not null. Not doing so will result in Null Pointer Exceptions.

**One last note**: I am using `Object` merely for illustration. In your case, it will be whatever type of object each column represent. Most likely, it will be `String`, but it could also be a number wrapper (i.e. `Integer`) or some custom data type you might've created for your scenario(s).